# Giving non-leaf nodes data/values in protovis

Tags: javascript, protovis

My data looks similar to this:

```
var root = {
    node1: {
        node2: 4,
        node3: 2
    },
    node4: {
        node5: 3
    }
};
```

Which is similar to how they suggest the data be laid out for tree structures in their examples. My question is this: how would I give values to node1 and node4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old question, but here's an answer anyway.
Check out http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/indent.html
Most notably,

```
var root = pv.dom(flare)
.root("flare")
.sort(function(a, b) pv.naturalOrder(a.nodeName, b.nodeName));

/* Recursively compute the package sizes. */
root.visitAfter(function(n) {
  if (n.firstChild) {
    n.nodeValue = pv.sum(n.childNodes, function(n) n.nodeValue);
  }
});
```

They load in their input using pv.dom(obj), then just recursively compute sums. In more general terms, you could use that interface to assign whatever values you want within the function you pass to `visitAfter`